# Smallest bounding box enclosing set of box on wraped 2D space

Tags: algorithm, 2d, bounding-box

I have finite 2D space with wrapped coordinates both way (I mean going left will wrap around into right edge, the same going for up/down).

I also have a set of box aligned to axes. These boxes have float coordinates inside space.

Problem: find smallest bounding box aligned to axes enclosing all boxes. Bounding box *CAN* be wrapped around.

Samples:

[image: Sample 1] [image: Sample2]

(Pink denotes space boundaries, red boxes needs to be enclosed, blue border denotes smallest possible bounding box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sweeping algorithm can be used to find the largest vertical gap, i.e. maximally distant two vertical lines that have no boxes between them.

Similarly, a sweeping algorithm can be used to find the largest horizontal gap. Obviously, both gaps can wrap around edges.

The shape left by removing the gaps from the 2D space is the smallest bounding box containing all boxes. I am not sure if it's guaranteed to have the smallest *area* of all the containing boxes, but there exists no  bounding box that has *both* dimensions smaller than this one. If it existed, it would define two gaps (vertical & horizontal) both larger than the maximal ones.

The sweeping to detect both gaps can be done in O(N * log N) where N is the number of boxes.

Answer (score 1):

The % of the total area enclosed by a bounding box will be:

% of total area enclosed by bounding box = (% of horizontal range enclosed by horizontal bounds) * (% of vertical range enclosed by vertical bounds)

Taking wrapping into account obviously. Therefore you can minimize the horizontal and vertical bounds independently in order to minimize the total area.

To minimize the horizontal bounds, you need to find the largest gap between one rectangle's right edge and the next's left edge. You can do this efficiently by sorting all edges (left and right) into a single list and iterating across it, incrementing a count when you get a left and decrementing when you get a right. Your largest gap is the biggest difference in x values when the count goes from 0 -> 1. You'll have to handle the wrap-around case specially, you could easily do this just by repeating the rectangles once horizontally, offset by the width of the total area. You also have to take into account wrapped-around rectangles when initializing the count at the start.

Then do likewise for the vertical bounds.